# Fullscreen in SDL1.2 makes positions false

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-1.2

My screen's resolution is 1920x1080. In order to have a fullscreen window, I call `SDL_SetVideoMode(1920, 1080, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);`. However, when I try to add an image on this screen with positions x = 0 and y = 0, it is positionned outside of the screen, like if my screen had a lower resolution than the window. It only shows a part of the window.

In order to see the image, I need to give `image.x` and `image.y` a value that is higher than 0. For example, here is the result with `image.x = 190` and `image.y = 100`:

[image]

As you can see, the image is stuck in the very left-upper corner. This can give you an idea of where it is, approximatively, when `image.x = 0` and `image.y = 0`.

Here is my code:

```
int     main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *image = NULL;
    SDL_Rect pos_image;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1920, 1080, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("SDL Test", NULL);
    image = SDL_LoadBMP("pack_images_sdz/image.bmp");
    SDL_SetColorKey(image, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0, 0, 255));
    pos_image.x = 190;
    pos_image.y = 100;
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, &pos_image);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    pause();
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to know why it is so. how comes the positions x = 0 and y = 0 are outside of the screen?

Comment: This is maybe a SDL1.2 bug.

Answer (score 0):

it can be the width and height of your image,
i sure don't know al lot about SDL1.2 but this problem might be from the image,
try another image and restart the program,
if it didnt work, i woud advise you to reinstall SDL1.2
good luck